# How to run python-socketio (eventlet WSGI server) over HTTPS

Tags: python, socket.io

I want to run the following eventlet WSGI server over HTTPS. I am trying to connect to the python server from JavaScript on my HTTPS enabled web-server.

**I would like the answer to describe how I would change this code below to work with HTTPS.**

```
import socketio
import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
from flask import Flask, render_template

sio = socketio.Server()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Serve the client-side application."""
    return render_template('index.html')

@sio.on('connect', namespace='/chat')
    def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connect ", sid)

@sio.on('chat message', namespace='/chat')
def message(sid, data):
    print("message ", data)
    sio.emit('reply', room=sid)

@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/chat')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # wrap Flask application with engineio's middleware
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)

    # deploy as an eventlet WSGI server
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), app)
```

This code was take from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-socketio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a Evenlet WSGI server over HTTPS all that’s needed is to pass an SSL-wrapped socket to the server() method like so:

```
wsgi.server(eventlet.wrap_ssl(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)),
                          certfile='cert.crt',
                          keyfile='private.key',
                          server_side=True),
        app)
```